Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libsqlite3odbc-0.9998.so' : file not found
I am attempting to run an SQLite3 console test application compiled for Windows with Visual Studio 2019 as an x86 32 bit application on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL2) using wine. The test app works fine under Windows 10. Under WSL, it is failing with the SQLDriverConnect() function call. SQLGetDiagRec() returns the following message (which has been updated with the correct SQLSTATE error code after correcting an error in the error message printing format from hex output to character output):
DriverConnect failed rc 0xffffffff SQLState = 01000 TextLength = 115 Message=[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libsqlite3odbc-0.9998.so' : file not found

The SQLSTATE value of 01000 indicates "General warning" which is really helpful. See Appendix A: ODBC Error Codes.
isql appears to connect just fine. The -k option is supposed to force isql to 'SQLDriverConnect' (https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/isql.1.html):
rickc@laptop-1:~/Documents$ isql -v -k "DRIVER={SQLite3};Database=/home/rickc/Documents/test2.db"
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> quit;

Note02: based on the following strace data, it appears that isql loads the libsqlite3odbc.so library file and continues while the obench application checks the library header and then fails. Is this a 64 bit vs 32 bit incompatibility problem?
Edit02 - strace output isql vs obench
I found a post discussing generating data for debugging which mentioned the strace utility. In the previous Edit01, which I have removed, I only provided the strace for the obench application. I retried this with both obench and isql to see the difference between the program which fails and the program which succeeds.
It looks like when the obench application runs, it opens the libsqlite3odbc.so file and reads the header, it reads the library header and then closes the file. However when the isql application reads opens the file and reads the header, it uses the mmap() function.
I interpret this to mean that the obench application opens the file, reads the header, and then fails because it doesn't like the header while the isql application opens the library file, reads the header, and then continues.
So is this a problem with 64 bit versus 32 bit? The ELF header for the library file indicates that it is 64 bit (see Wikipedia: Executable and Linkable Format - File header).
The point in the strace isql log where the libsqlite3odbc.so library is opened looks like the following:
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libsqlite3odbc.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\213\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=198304, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 201344, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fefcca5c000
mmap(0x7fefcca64000, 114688, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x8000) = 0x7fefcca64000
mmap(0x7fefcca80000, 28672, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x24000) = 0x7fefcca80000
mmap(0x7fefcca87000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2a000) = 0x7fefcca87000
mmap(0x7fefcca8d000, 640, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fefcca8d000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=47367, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 47367, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fefcca50000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1358520, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 1362360, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fefcc903000
mmap(0x7fefcc921000, 966656, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e000) = 0x7fefcc921000
mmap(0x7fefcca0d000, 241664, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x10a000) = 0x7fefcca0d000
mmap(0x7fefcca48000, 32768, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x144000) = 0x7fefcca48000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=940560, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 942344, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fefcc81c000
mmap(0x7fefcc82a000, 507904, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xe000) = 0x7fefcc82a000
mmap(0x7fefcc8a6000, 372736, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x8a000) = 0x7fefcc8a6000
mmap(0x7fefcc901000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xe4000) = 0x7fefcc901000
close(3)
mprotect(0x7fefcc901000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fefcca48000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fefcca87000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fefcca50000, 47367)           = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/C.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/C/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/C.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/C/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

The place in the strace obench trace log where libsqlite3odbc.so is opened looks like:
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libsqlite3odbc.so", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_CLOEXEC) = 11
read(11, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\213\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
close(11)                               = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/C.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/C/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/C.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/C.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/C/LC_MESSAGES/libc.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/rickc/devart.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_APPEND, 0666) = 11

The console application explained
The console application first generates a list of ODBC drivers installed. This works correctly providing a list of the two SQLite ODBC drivers installed before the application fails when attempting the SQLDriverConnect() function call:
rickc@laptop-1:~/Documents$ wine obench -dsn "Driver={SQLite3};Database=/home/rickc/Documents/test2.db" -init -v -tpc 200 -clients 4
ListDrivers()
 Driver={SQLite}
 Driver={SQLite3}
  SQLDrivers()  SQL_NO_DATA
 Driver={SQLite3}
Scale factor value: 1
Number of clients: 4
Number of transactions per client: 200

Initializing dataset...
CreateDatabase dsn="Driver={SQLite3};Database=/home/rickc/Documents/test2.db"
SQLDriverConnect()   SQLDriverConnect()  SQL_ERROR
DriverConnect failed rc 0xffffffff SQLState = 01000 TextLength = 115 Message=[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libsqlite3odbc-0.9998.so' : file not found

System files
I have the following in /etc/odbcinst.ini:
rickc@laptop-1:~/Documents$ cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[SQLite]
Description=SQLite ODBC Driver
Driver=libsqliteodbc.so
Setup=libsqliteodbc.so
UsageCount=1

[SQLite3]
Description=SQLite3 ODBC Driver
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libsqlite3odbc-0.9998.so
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libsqlite3odbc-0.9998.so
UsageCount=1

Testing the ODBC environment with odbcinst:
rickc@laptop-1:~$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.9
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/rickc/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8

When I ls the directory, the files exist. I used chmod +x to make the libsqlite3odbc-0.9998.so executable in case that was the problem but no change in application behavior:
rickc@laptop-1:~/Documents$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/
total 196
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 198304 Dec  5  2021 libsqlite3odbc-0.9998.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24 Dec  5  2021 libsqlite3odbc.so -> libsqlite3odbc-0.9998.so

I have seen a post which mentions setting the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I did so with no change in application behavior:
rickc@laptop-1:~/Documents$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc
rickc@laptop-1:~/Documents$ env | grep PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc

I've also seen a post that mentions missing library dependencies and to check with ldd. It appears everything needed is installed:
rickc@laptop-1:~/Documents$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libsqlite3odbc.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff08972000)
        libsqlite3.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007fa337670000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa337447000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa337360000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa3377fd000)
rickc@laptop-1:~/Documents$ ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libsqlite3odbc-0.9998.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd8adfd000)
        libsqlite3.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f5c157ba000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5c15591000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5c154aa000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5c15947000)

Source code of createDatabase()
The specific createDatabase() function in the console test application that is failing is as follows:
int rcMessage (const char *pmsg, SQLRETURN rc) {
        switch (rc) {
        case SQL_SUCCESS:
            // fprintf (stderr, "  %s  SQL_SUCCESS\n", pmsg);
            break;
        case SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO:
                fprintf (stderr, "  %s  SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO\n", pmsg);
            break;
        case SQL_NO_DATA:
                fprintf (stderr, "  %s  SQL_NO_DATA\n", pmsg);
            break;
        case SQL_ERROR:
                fprintf (stderr, "  %s  SQL_ERROR\n", pmsg);
            break;
        case SQL_INVALID_HANDLE:
                fprintf (stderr, "  %s  SQL_INVALID_HANDLE\n", pmsg);
            break;
        case SQL_STILL_EXECUTING:
                fprintf (stderr, "  %s  SQL_STILL_EXECUTING\n", pmsg);
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "  %s  default 0x%x\n", pmsg, rc);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
static void createDatabase()
{
    int dotrans = 0, i;
    long accountsnb = 0;
    SQLHENV env = NULL;
    SQLHDBC dbc = NULL;
    SQLRETURN rc;
    SQLHSTMT s;
    char sqlbuf[1024] = {0};

    fprintf(stderr, "CreateDatabase dsn=\"%s\"\n", dsn);
    rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env);
    rcMessage ("SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV)", rc);
    rc= SQLSetEnvAttr(env, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER) SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    rcMessage ("SQLSetEnvAttr()", rc);
    rc = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, env, &dbc);
    rcMessage ("SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC)", rc);
    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC) failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "SQLDriverConnect() ");
    rc = SQLDriverConnect(dbc, NULL, (SQLCHAR *) dsn, SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE | SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
    rcMessage ("SQLDriverConnect()", rc);

    if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(rc)) {
        SQLCHAR     SQLState[8] = {0};
        SQLINTEGER  NativeErrorPtr = 0;
        SQLSMALLINT RecNumber = 1;
        SQLCHAR     MessageText[256] = {0};
        SQLSMALLINT  TextLength = 0, BufferLength = 255;

        SQLGetDiagRec(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, dbc, RecNumber, SQLState, &NativeErrorPtr, MessageText, BufferLength, &TextLength);
        fprintf(stderr, "DriverConnect failed rc 0x%x SQLState = %x%x TextLength = %d Message=%s\n", rc, SQLState[0], SQLState[1], TextLength, MessageText);
        exit(1);
    }
// lots of code that is never executed due to exit, deleted.
}

ODBC trace log
After finding how to turn on ODBC trace logging, I ran the application again to generate an ODBC trace log.
To turn on the ODBC trace log, I added the following directives to the top of the /etc/odbcinst.ini file (see Enabling ODBC Tracing):
[ODBC]
Trace=Yes
TraceFile=/home/rickc/devart.log

The trace log generated is not that helpful without the unixODBC source code.
[ODBC][11507][1718832176.788717][SQLDriverConnect.c][748]
                Entry:
                        Connection = 0x7efadb70
                        Window Hdl = (nil)
                        Str In = [DRIVER={SQLite3};Database=/home/rickc/Documents/test2.db][length = 56 (SQL_NTS)]
                        Str Out = 0x31b06c
                        Str Out Max = 2048
                        Str Out Ptr = (nil)
                        Completion = 1
[ODBC][11507][1718832176.789519][SQLConnect.c][1141]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libsqlite3odbc.so' : file not found
[ODBC][11507][1718832176.790640][SQLGetDiagRec.c][677]
                Entry:
                        Connection = 0x7efadb70
                        Rec Number = 1
                        SQLState = 0x31feb8
                        Native = 0x31f98c
                        Message Text = 0x31fdb8
                        Buffer Length = 255
                        Text Len Ptr = 0x31f9a0
[ODBC][11507][1718832176.790677][SQLGetDiagRec.c][726]
                Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
                        SQLState = 01000
                        Native = 0x31f98c -> 0 (32 bits)
                        Message Text = [[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libsqlite3odbc.so' : file not found]

wine debug output
This is the truncated output when running the application with wine debug output. It also is not very helpful.
rickc@laptop-1:~/Documents$ WINEDEBUG=odbc wine obench -dsn "Driver={SQLite3};Database=/home/rickc/Documents/test2.db" -init -v -tpc 200 -clients 4
0024:trace:odbc:DllMain proxy ODBC: 70C00000,1,0031FD24
ListDrivers()

...  stuff deleted

Initializing dataset...
CreateDatabase dsn="Driver={SQLite3};Database=/home/rickc/Documents/test2.db"
0024:trace:odbc:SQLAllocHandle (HandleType 1, InputHandle 00000000, OutputHandle 0031F99C)
0024:trace:odbc:SQLAllocHandle Returning 0, Handle 7DAA1480
0024:trace:odbc:SQLSetEnvAttr (EnvironmentHandle 7DAA1480, Attribute 200, Value 00000003, StringLength 0)
0024:trace:odbc:SQLSetEnvAttr Returning 0
0024:trace:odbc:SQLAllocHandle (HandleType 2, InputHandle 7DAA1480, OutputHandle 0031F9A8)
0024:trace:odbc:SQLAllocHandle Returning 0, Handle 7DAA1B30
SQLDriverConnect() 0024:trace:odbc:SQLDriverConnect (hdbc 7DAA1B30, hwnd 00000000, ConnectionString "", Length -3, conn_str_out 00000000, conn_str_out_max 0, ptr_conn_str_out 00000000, driver_completion 1)
0024:trace:odbc:SQLDriverConnect Returning -1
  SQLDriverConnect()  SQL_ERROR
0024:trace:odbc:SQLGetDiagRec (HandleType 2, Handle 7DAA1B30, RecNumber 1, Sqlstate 0031FEB8, NativeError 0031F98C, MessageText 0031FDB8, BufferLength 255, TextLength 0031F9A0)
0024:trace:odbc:SQLGetDiagRec Returning 0
DriverConnect failed rc 0xffffffff SQLState = 3031 TextLength = 115 Message=[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libsqlite3odbc-0.9998.so' : file not found
0024:trace:odbc:DllMain proxy ODBC: 70C00000,0,00000001

The function for listing the available ODBC drivers, works fine but then it is not actually accessing the SQLite ODBC driver itself.

Note: based on the strace data, it appears that there is at least one missing Windows DLL in the wine Windows file hierarchy. The missing DLL is mscoree.dll. There may be others. Thanks to https://github.com/lurcher/unixODBC/issues/62

After comparing the strace log output generated by the isql application, which works, and the obench application, which fails, it is beginning to look like when obench opens the libsqlite3odbc.so library and reads the ELF data in the header, the program sees a problem and fails. Could this be a 64 bit library being used with a 32 bit application problem?
